# forcing a footnote to split across mutiple pages

Tags: footnotes

I have a long footnote appearing at the bottom of a page that includes a long equation. LaTeX is splitting the equation, placing the last bit on the next page, but keeping all of the footnote on the current page. I'd prefer that it do the opposite. Any suggestions? I've already set

```
\allowdisplaybreaks[1]
\interfootnotelinepenalty=0
```

but neither helps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's better not to use `\allowdisplaybreaks` except when writing the document; disable it for the final version, adding `\displaybreak` where needed: breaking displays well is too difficult for a machine.

Comment: I suggest you try to load [bigfoot](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) in your preamble (`\usepackage{bigfoot}`). In provides a much more advance algorithm for placing footnotes.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.